# CJuiDatePicker, YII Date Picker required

Tags: php, yii, requiredfieldvalidator

is there a way to validate CJuiDatePicker as a required field?

```
<?php     
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
                                    'model'=>$model,
                                    'attribute'=>'bdate',
                                    'options'=>array( 
                                                'showAnim'=>'fadeIn', 
                                                'dateFormat'=>'mm/dd/yy',
                                                'changeMonth'=>true,
                                                'changeYear'=>true,
                                                'minDate'=>'01/01/1900',
                                                'yearRange' => '-200:+0',
                                                'maxDate'=>'0',
                                                ),
                                    'htmlOptions'=>array('readonly' => true, 'class' => "form-control", 'required'=> 'true', 'value'=>isset($_SESSION["bdate"])?$_SESSION["bdate"]:'')
                            ));
                        ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare "bdate" as a required attribute in your model:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            ...
            array('bdate', 'required'),
            ...
        );
    }
```

Is there a problem?

Comment: Please provide more info how exactly it's not working. In my app I use CJuiDatePicker as a required field and it does work.

Comment: Here's part of my code:

$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
            'name'=>'Customer[bdate]',
         
             'options'=>array(
             'changeMonth'=>true,
                   'changeYear'=>true,
                   'minDateTime'=>'js:new Date(' . date('Y,m-1,d,H,i') . ')',
                'showAnim'=>'fadeIn',
            ),
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'class'=>"form-control",
            ),
        ));

Comment: and:



<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#Customer_bdate").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
     $("#Customer_bdate").attr('value', <?php echo (isset($_SESSION["bdate"])?'null':'null');?>);
        $("#Customer_bdate").datepicker({  changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,maxDate: new Date,  yearRange: '1900:+1'  });
    document.getElementById("Customer_bdate").required=true;
    });
</script>

Comment: even i've set it to null, form is still submitted.